# Xcode Deployment Target: Should I trust "Compiler Default"?

Tags: iphone

I have set my target deployment target to be: "Compiler Default".  Should I trust that Xcode will do the right thing?  The right thing being:

> Compiler Default - Code will load on
>   any iPhone OS system that supports the
>   APIs that are used.

I'd like my app to run on any iPhone whose OS supports the APIs I use.  If an API is unavailable, then I don't want my app to run on that iPhone (or iPod).

The reason I ask is that I don't observe it doing the right thing, as far as I can tell, and I have no older OS devices to test this.

Comment: it's a circular question, right?  you only want to deploy to devices which support the particular apis, but you haven't defined the apis yet.  pick a target (OS 3.0 for example) and then if you try to include API's not supported by that version, you will get errors when attempting compilation.  Unless, of course, you need something in 3.1 (or 3.2 or 5.x - someday)